# need working example of fb:like in UIWebView with edge.create/remove event firing

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

**summary in short:** edge.create stopped firing in embedded HTML inside UIWebView (and I did not change anything in code for a while) - any ideas how can I get it back?

---

I have iOS application which has UIWebView with Facebook Like button.
[image]

User logs into Facebook BEFORE this dialog appears, so there is no login logic happening.

I can click like/unlike - and it works fine - but it used to close the dialog, and few days ago this broke. Closing the dialog was achieve by subscribing to edge.create / edge.remove events.

Here is my HTML page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type='text/css'>
            * { -webkit-touch-callout: none; -webkit-user-select: none; }
            body { margin:0px; }
            .fb_edge_comment_widget { display: none !important; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>                   
        <div id='fb-root'></div>
        <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1'></script>
        <script>
            function forwardEvent(name) {
                var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                iframe.setAttribute('src', 'event:' + name);
                document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
                iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);  
            };
            function beginForwardingEvent(name) {
                FB.Event.subscribe(name, function(r) { forwardEvent(name); });
            };
            function beginForwardingEvents(names) {
                for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                    beginForwardingEvent(names[i]);
                }
            };
            beginForwardingEvents(['edge.create', 'edge.remove', 'xfbml.render']);
        </script>    
        <fb:like    href='%@' 
                    send='false' 
                    layout='%@' 
                    width='%.0f' 
                    show_faces='%@' 
                    action='%@' 
                    colorscheme='%@' 
                    font='%@'
                    ></fb:like>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is how i capture events in Objective-C code:

```
- (void)didObserveFacebookEvent:(NSString *)fbEvent {
    if ([fbEvent isEqualToString:@"edge.create"] && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(facebookLikeViewDidLike:)])
        [_delegate facebookLikeViewDidLike:self];
    else if ([fbEvent isEqualToString:@"edge.remove"] && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(facebookLikeViewDidUnlike:)])
        [_delegate facebookLikeViewDidUnlike:self];
    else if ([fbEvent isEqualToString:@"xfbml.render"] && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(facebookLikeViewDidRender:)])
        [_delegate facebookLikeViewDidRender:self];
}


- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    // Allow loading Like button XFBML from file
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"file"])
        return YES;

    // Allow loading about:blank, etc.
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"about"])
        return YES;

    // Block loading of 'event:*', our scheme for forwarding Facebook JS SDK events to native code
    else if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"event"]) {
        [self didObserveFacebookEvent:request.URL.resourceSpecifier];
        return NO;
    }
  ....
}
```

so once again - edge.create stopped firing (and I did not change anything in code for a while) - any ideas how can I get it back?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
though there is a [FB bug reported](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332010483521261?browse=search_4f8837266b7b09514484175), i still would like to understand why it does work on [FBRELL](http://www.fbrell.com/saved/54214b4bf5fa886951ebe68d938e2865) site but does not work inside iOS UIWebView. May be there is a tweak required for iOS dialog? Is there a workaround for this? Started the bounty hoping to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the edge.create event won't fire within the local HTML file. Whether this is by chance or design, I'm unsure, but I've done a few things and got this to work:

1. Hosted the 'FacebookLikeView.html' file on my own server, substituting the format specifiers for the actual values i want, e.g. `action='%@'` is now explicitly `action='like'`.
2. Removed everything from the `load` method in FacebookLikeView.m and replaced it with the line:

   ```
   [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourhost.com/FacebookLikeView.html"]]];
   ```
3. Changed the line in the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` method:

   ```
   if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"file"])
       return YES;
   ```

   to

   ```
   if ([request.URL.host hasSuffix:@"yourhost.com"]) 
       return YES;
   ```

It's not the answer you were hoping for, but I hope this gives you some clues, and at the very least helps to get it working in the meantime.

Comment: YES! that was it - sorry for the late reply. These events will fire only with remote HTML file.